# sqlalchemy connection identical credentials refused when run on different machines

Tags: python, mysql, linux, windows, sqlalchemy

I have a problem which seems impossible to me, meaning I am fundamentally misunderstanding something. I've written a simple API using flask (a python library). This api, among other things, connects to a mysql server running on a remote web server. I am using the sqlalchemy library to perform this connection.

The connection string is quite simple. It looks like this:

```
    db =create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}'.format(user=Constants.Sql.USER, password=Constants.Sql.PASS, host=Constants.Sql.HOST, port=Constants.Sql.PORT, database=Constants.Sql.DATABASE))
    connection = db.connect()
```

On my development machine this all works fine. However, when I deploy the api to a different remote machine, it doesn't work. I get the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'domain' (using password: YES) None None
```

This doesn't make any sense to me because it is using exactly the same credentials (they are hard coded).

The working environment is a windows machine, the environment throwing the error is ubuntu 14.04. Both the windows and ubuntu machines are remote to the web server on which the database is running, so it can't be some weird localhost thing.

I am totally stumped with this. If anyone could give me some advice I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the database only accepts connections from a particular IP address.  That would explain why same username and password would succeed on one and fail on the other.

GRANT includes IP address information.  Look at the MySQL documentation.  Or this tutorial:

https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/mysql/add-user-mysql/

Comment: The link is no more avaliable.